# How to import a CSV file into a DB2 database using .NET?

Tags: database, vb.net, csv, db2, import

I am doing a Windows application. How do I import a CSV file into DB2 database table? Through google I got one command:

```
IMPORT FROM 'C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\sample.csv' OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL | METHOD P (1, 2, 3) MESSAGES "C:\messages.txt" INSERT INTO myTable(myTable_col1,myTable_col2,myTable_col3);
```

But this is also not working, so is there any other command or any kind of code in .NET?

Comment: does this help you out: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BulkCopy. (See *[DB2BulkCopy Class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2BulkCopyClass.html)*) Here's some C# code:

```
using (DB2BulkCopy bc = new DB2BulkCopy(myConnectionString))
        {
            bc.DestinationTableName = myDestinationTableName;
            bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 120;
            bc.WriteToServer(myDataReader);
            bc.Close();
        }
```